# using mysql transaction in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, nested

I want to do sth like below .There is one procedure which contains two other procedures. 
The first one inserts some date into my 'User' table and the second do the same to some other tables. The problem is , when I call this SP with a wrong 'CountryID' which leads the process to an error as expected, the first SP (InsertUsername) commits!
obviously what I want is having a roll back after this error .

```
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION ;

SET @Username =  _Username;

CALL `InsertUsername` (
@Username , @UserID
);

CALL `InsertAddress` (
@UserID , _CountryID , _AdderssText , _PostalCode 
);

COMMIT ;

END
```

Comment: What does `InsertUsername` look like? Does it start/commit its own transaction?

Comment: No it doesn't. it actually looks like this :
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO `user`(`UserID`,`Username`) VALUES (NULL , _Username) ;
 
SELECT userid INTO _UserID FROM  user WHERE username = _Username ;

END

Comment: Strange, are you sure that `user` and `address` are InnoDB tables?

Comment: Yes , I've checked it and for sure they are InnoDB. the point is that when I use transaction for a procedure without any calls in it, it works just right, but in a SP like above it doesn't , any ideas? or ask to explain more if the condition is not yet clear.

Comment: Does `InsertAddress` have `START TRANSACTION` inside it?  If it does, that will cause an implicit commit of the existing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that transactions didn't work as expected until we defined exit handlers in the stored procedures.

We created a fairly crude one-liner for use as a default:

```
declare exit handler for SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION begin show warnings limit 5; rollback; end;
```

Comment: I tried it and it's always giving me an error and doesn't execute the procedure's steps.. I'm using mysql.
any help plz!!

Comment: thank you!! you really pointed me to the correct direction!! It worked for me !! :)

Answer (score 0):

like simon.evans said I finally found the correct answer and it worked for me so I want to add more details :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add`(IN serial_number VARCHAR(20), IN tarnsaction_type INT
, OUT errcode VARCHAR(3))
BEGIN

DECLARE      my_balance NUMERIC(15,3);
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN

  ROLLBACK;
  SET errcode = '058';
  END;

 CALL procedure2(p_account_id,v_account_balance);
 #do what ever you want to do here

END$$
```

If you have a question ask me
because I had the same problem and finally I found this answer :)